# The percentage of answered questions seems to have suddenly jumped, what happened?

Tags: discussion

When I asked whether or not our Beta label would be removed, we were at about 60% answered, and the answer was that we would remain in Beta because we weren't at 70% answered. Now we're "suddenly" at 69% answered and I wonder how that happened?

Comment: I don't know. There has been an uptick in activity from a few relatively new users, but it seems hard to believe it's enough to account for 9 percentage points. It could also be due to closed questions aging out and being auto-deleted. Probably a mix of both factors.

Comment: @CareyGregory Interesting indeed, thanks!

Comment: I have had about 10 questions being auto-deleted since then... Great website! What a surprise that user retention is so low.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Why are you complaining about this here? You know perfectly well we have absolutely no control over auto deletions. You need to complain on meta.stackexchange.

Comment: @CareyGregory I complained on meta.stackexchange: [Decrease the required view count to prevent Roomba deletion when score = 0 on smaller sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355097/178179). I am also complaining about this here since it especially affects medical SE.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt That makes no sense because _we can't do anything about it_. It's like going to a restaurant and complaining to the dishwasher about the quality of your meal.

Comment: @CareyGregory users and mods here can 1)  cast more upvotes to avoid this issue 2) upvote the reported issue to Meta (or  raise the awareness differently). You, as a mod, can  raise the issue more directly with the CM.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt 1) You expect mods to upvote your questions just to keep them from being deleted? That's not what upvotes are for, and and it's not our job. 2) How do you know one or more mods didn't upvote your meta question? It has 34 upvotes. And once again, upvoting your meta questions also isn't our job. 3) No, mods can't take the issue to the CM team any more directly than you can. What I find troubling is that you constantly blame mods here for everything you dislike (which is a lot) whether we have any control over it or not. You're really quite unfair and hostile with mods.

Comment: @CareyGregory 1) No, just saying that users, including mods, could cast upvotes more often on good questions 2) idk 3) they likely are more visible. I don't blame mods. The SE system is responsible for this mess.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I agree with you on #1 but nobody can make people vote. I wish they would raise more flags too, but most people don't do that either. CM isn't going to take change requests from mods through back channels. We would have to post on meta just like anyone else. If you don't blame mods, it's hard to tell that sometimes.